# How use Send() if the content has "" in it ? (autoIt)

Tags: autoit

```
 Run("cmd.exe")
Global $String = "wmic process where name="example.exe" get commandline"
Send($String)
```

Result :

```
Global $String = "wmic process where name="example.exe" get commandline"
Global $String = "wmic process where name="^ ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use single quotes to surround your string.

```
$string = 'test "example" and more stuff'
```

Or you can "escape" your double quotes by doubling them like stated in the [Strings description](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_datatypes.htm) of the Datatypes in AutoIt.

```
$string = "test ""example"" and more stuff"
```